# ‘Come in’ or ‘come inside’ the elevator?

Tags: grammar

Which is the preferred use: ‘come in’ or ‘come inside’ when giving a direction into the elevator?

Comment: 'Get in' would be the only one heard at all regularly in the UK, but even that would be normally hedged to say 'There's room for a small one'.

Comment: I just realised that I may have misunderstood this question.  Do you mean when someone already inside the elevator *invites* someone outside it to get in?  If so, can you make this more clear in your question?

Comment: The automatic opening of the doors indicates that anyone wanting to get in should get on with it before the door automatically closes. Why is an invitation needed ?

Comment: @NigelJ often the lift (elevator) is crowded, and the person outside is unsure whether they could fit in, or whether it would be polite to try.  In this case, an invitation is helpful.

Comment: @MaxWilliams  If it's that crowded, I'll take the stairs :)

Answer (score 1):

Neither is idiomatic. A [google ngrams shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=come+in+the+elevator%2C+come+inside+the+elevator%2C+get+on+the+elevator&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cget%20on%20the%20elevator%3B%2Cc0), **get on the elevator** is the most common use.

[image]

Comment: "Get in the elevator" is idiomatic too, although (surprisingly), not as common as "get on", according to ngrams at least.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=come+in+the+elevator%2Ccome+inside+the+elevator%2Cget+on+the+elevator%2C+get+in+the+elevator&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cget%20on%20the%20elevator%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20in%20the%20elevator%3B%2Cc0  To me, you'd get *in* it because you go **in**side it.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Good catch.

Answer (score -1):

You could also say 'Come into the lift'